# django rest framework: order of decorators, auth classes, dispatch to be called

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Very confused about the order of decorators, auth classes, dispatch to be called in djangorestframework. It seems that it is a little different from my django framework knowledge.

Some codes:

```
#operation_logger: customized decorator
class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)#A
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)#B

    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))#C
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)#D
    @method_decorator(operation_logger)#E
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):#F
       return super(FileView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @method_decorator(operation_logger)#G
    def post(self, request):#H
        print "xxxxpost"
```

**What is the order of (A),B,C,D,E,F,G,H to be called when handling requests?**
It seems that B is called after F but before G and H?

By the way, at beginning, my project was traditional django project. I know that request should go through all the middlewares. Now, I added a new app, which hosts APIs by DRF. **I am not sure whether my request to APIs will go through all  the middlewares or not?**

Thanks

Comment: You mean: the order in which the functions are called during import?

Comment: @RégisB. I mean the order when handling requests. I already updated my post. Thanks

Comment: So, with dispatch(), the order work when dispatch is created by interpreter, then the decorator @method_decorator is applied, this decorator return a callable (as all decorator do), after the next decorator  does  the same, then the last result is assigned to dispatch()

Comment: Can you fix the indentation, please? It's confusing, because DRF also supports bare functions as views and I don't want to break it with an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *call* order is as you specified:

1. `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)`
2. `@method_decorator(operation_logger)` (#E)
3. `dispatch()` calls `initial()` which calls `check_permissions()` which evaluates `permission_classes` (#B).
4. `@method_decorator(operation_logger)` (#G)
5. `post()`

One thing won't work, however:

`@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))` on the method [adds](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/0f61c9ec290ccf41bbb3c28ba91785a7430676c3/rest_framework/decorators.py#L106) a `permission_classes` field to the callable (whatever that is) returned by (#E). This doesn't work with class-based views and is thus essentially a no-op.

Other parts have no fixed order, but are used on demand:

The authenticator is called whenever needed, i.e. when [user](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/0f61c9ec290ccf41bbb3c28ba91785a7430676c3/rest_framework/request.py#L189) or [authentication](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/0f61c9ec290ccf41bbb3c28ba91785a7430676c3/rest_framework/request.py#L212) information is accessed on the request object.

Same thing for `parser_classes`. These get passed to the request object and used lazily when request information is accessed, e.g. [`request.data`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/0f61c9ec290ccf41bbb3c28ba91785a7430676c3/rest_framework/request.py#L183).

Comment: Thanks. How to make sure operation_logger run after authentication finished? I tried to put it at position G, which works fine. But no idea whether it is the only solution to make opertion_logger run after authentication finished.

Comment: @BAE I don't understand *finished* in this regard. You can ask the request object if the request is authenticated or not. This makes the authenticator run the first time you do it, but afterwards the result is cached. The request, however, doesn't change it's "non-authenticated" state to something else, it just determines the authentication state.

Comment: You are right. It is what I mean. Thanks. at beginning, my project was traditional django project. I know that request should go through all the middlewares. Now, I added a new app, which hosts APIs by DRF. **I am not sure whether my request to APIs will go through all  the middlewares or not?**

Comment: So, this is actually an XY problem? You actually want to test, if DRF views use Django's middleware? An `APIView` is just a normal django view with extra fancy. For example, `APIViews` automatically have `csrf_exempt` set, but the API views still use the normal django request-response flow